# Phrase query in elasticsearch considers docFreq for each component word?

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase

I'm searching for a phrase in a corpus of documents (using elasticsearch 5.5.1) that includes annual company reports. I'm searching for a phrase, the query context looks like the following:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [{ "match_phrase": { "content": {"query": "computer vision"}}}
```

In looking at the explanation of the results returned, it looks like the term frequency is calculated the correct (or what I expect) way i.e., it returns the number of times the phrase occurs in the doc. However, the idf calculation sums the results for each of the component words of the phrase. For instance, in the phrase "computer vision", it calculates the docFreq for "computer" and the docFeq for "vision" separately and sums the log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) for each word. That is not quite what I expected - I would have thought that docFreq like term frequency would be based on number of occurrences of the exact phrase. Any help would be much appreciated.